# Symfony 2 Sonata Admin - Custom sort in ListMapper

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have a `Customer` entity with fields such as FirstName, LastName.

Also I have a method in the entity like this:

```
public function getFullName() {
        return sprintf("%s %s", $this->getLastName(), $this->getFirstName());
}
```

My `configureListFields` function looks like the following:

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->add('fullName')
        ->add('birthday')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('phone')
    ;
}
```

How can I make the field **fullName** sortable?

How can I add custom sort criteria with or without Doctrine ORM?

Comment: This link is going to help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947799/problems-showing-fields-with-sonata-admin-symfony-2-0

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution to this ?? I am stuck with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can hack using a custom template if it is OK to sort only on lastname.

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->add('last', null, array(
            'sortable' => true,
            'template' => 'YourAdminBundle:CRUD:fullname.html.twig')
        ->add('birthday')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('phone')
    ;
}
```

in your template :

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}
{% block field%}
{{ object.lastName }} {{ object.firstName }} 
{% endblock %}
```

The problem is that it will only sort on lastName and not lastName firstName :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:

Entity:

```
public function getTextFullName() 
{
   return $this->LastName . $this->FirstName;
}
```

And List Fieds:

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->add('textFullName')
        ->add('birthday')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('phone')
    ;
}
```